# $.event.trigger not working on DOM elements

Tags: jquery, events

From what I have read, this should work...

```
$('#test').on "newMessage", ->
  alert('test')

$(document).on "newMessage", ->
  alert('document')

$.event.trigger('newMessage')
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/Nbdyb/

Can someone help me understand why I never get a 'test' alert?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `newMessage` handler registered in the `#test` element, in order to trigger that the event should be triggered in that element or in one of its decedents(event bubbling).

it should be

```
$('#test').trigger('newMessage')
```

Comment: I am trying to use `on/trigger` as a basic pubsub model.  When I trigger an event, I won't know all of the elements that have subscribed.  Documentation on using `$.event.trigger` implies you can trigger events for all subscribing without being explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Since $.event isn't officially documented, I compared the current source with some older version of jQuery and found a TODO about removing this 'feature'.  At least its explained why it doesnt work anymore.

This is the block of code that used to allow this to work.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L322-335

The current code now just assigns `document` as the element if no element is passed in.  Whcih is why it worked fine for document and window.

Looks like I will be needing a separate library if i want anonymous pupsub...

Answer (score 0):

When I upgrade the `jquery` from **v1.7.1** to **v1.11.1**+, I found that `$.event.trigger()` doesn't work any more.

Still don't know why, but here is an alternative solution for event-driven operations (not DOM-based event handling):

---

Old days :

```
// handler
$(anyElement).on('Foo:SelfDefined:Event', function(event){
    console.log( event.self_data_1 );
    console.log( event.self_data_2 );
});
------------------
// trigger handler
var evOpts = {
    type        : 'Foo:SelfDefined:Event',
    self_data_1 : 'foo',
    self_data_2 : 'bar'
};
$.event.trigger( evOpts );
```

Now :

```
// handler
$(document).on('Foo:SelfDefined:Event', function(event, evData){
    console.log( evData.self_data_1 );
    console.log( evData.self_data_2 );
});
------------------
// trigger handler
var evData = {
    type        : 'Foo:SelfDefined:Event',
    self_data_1 : 'foo',
    self_data_2 : 'bar'
};
$(document).trigger(evData.type, evData);
```

**Note:** If element A trigger a event, only it's parent node or itself can listen and attach handler to that event, that's why this solution is not good for DOM-based event handling.